# Angular filter on object key in response

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have Json request as below. I need to filter only values from key with `intrsted` in table.I am new to filters and handling key in angular. I attached my JSON request and response, need assistane.

JSON:

```
var customer = 
 [
  [
    {
      "businessuserid": 44,
      "businessusername": "rk business New",
      "businessusermobile": "00",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": false,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "riteshnew@gmail.com",
      "upin": "000044"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "approved": true,
      "businessuserid": 43,
      "businessusername": "Cakey Bakes",
      "businessusermobile": "8050663763",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": true,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "preethi@groupz.com",
      "upin": "000043"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "intrsted": true,
      "attended": false,
      "businessuserid": 44,
      "businessusername": "rk business New",
      "businessusermobile": "00",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": false,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "riteshnew@gmail.com",
      "upin": "000044"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "intrsted": true,
      "attended": false,
      "businessuserid": 52,
      "businessusername": "Cars workshop",
      "businessusermobile": "9535000636",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": true,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "preethi@car.com",
      "upin": "000052"
    }
  ]
```

Html:

```
 <table ng-repeat="item in customers | filter: { intrsted: true }">
    <td>{{item.businessusername}}</td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your filter usage. Problem is at your **ng-repeat** usage. If you double check your json object you will see your every item is another array so you need to use inner object as array. Fix your html like this

```
<table ng-repeat="item in customers | filter: { intrsted: true }">
    <td>{{item[0].businessusername}}</td>
</table>
```

You see your **item** is just an another array so use it like item[0] and you will get the result you want...

**UPDATE**

for showing inner array list on html use second ng-repeat inside of first ng-repeat...

```
<table ng-repeat="item in customers | filter: { intrsted: true }">
    <td ng-repeat="customer in item">{{customer.businessusername}}</td>
</table>
```

Comment: for now I have one array. If it is more than one how can I dynamically populate item[1]?

Comment: Thanks a lot,it was helpful